# CSS responsive horizontal and vertical layout

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design, responsive

I am trying to build a responsive layout:

Small viewports (e.g. max-width 750px):

```
    +---------------+
    |      1        |
    +----+-----+----+
    |  2 |     |    |
    +----+  4  |  5 |
    |  3 |     |    |
    +----+-----+----+
```

Large viewports (min-width 751px):

```
    +---+---+---+---+
    | 1 |   |   |   |
    +---+ 3 | 4 | 5 |
    | 2 |   |   |   |
    +---+---+---+---+
```

I tried with flex, display: table and others. The only solution I found is to duplicate the markup, but that's not ideal. Is there any other possibility?

Boxes have variable-length text content, thus unfortunately **fixed height** is not an option.

Comment: `flex` should work. specifically check [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) flex property.

Comment: ..also provide the code you have tried.

Comment: use `bootstrap` grid structure. it will help you in many ways for responsive design. Here's the [link](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: @Mr_Green the problem with flex is that I can not implement it using only one flex container. I need two separate flex containers (one for the vertically aligned boxes and one for the others), so order is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

I did it using `flexbox` and `position: relative`.

**[Working Fiddle](http://codepen.io/Mr_Green/pen/LRXXwV)**

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 400px;
}
.box {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #ccc;
  flex: 1;
  height: calc(100% / 3);
  line-height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.one {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
}
.two,
.four,
.five,
.six {
  flex: 1 0 calc(100% / 3);
  /*   min-width: calc(100% / 4) */
}
.four,
.five,
.six {
  height: calc(200% / 3);
}
.three {
  order: 1;
  max-width: calc(100% / 3);
  top: calc(-100% + (200% / 3));
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .one {} .one,
  .two,
  .three,
  .four,
  .five {
    flex: 1 0 calc(100% / 4);
    max-width: calc(100% / 4);
    top: 0px;
  }
  .one,
  .two {
    height: calc(100% / 2);
  }
  .three,
  .four,
  .five {
    height: 100%;
  }
  .two {
    order: 1;
    top: calc(-100% / 2);
  }
  .three {
    order: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="box one">1</div>
  <div class="box two">2</div>
  <div class="box three">3</div>
  <div class="box four">4</div>
  <div class="box five">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This achieves exactly what I want, but the height of the containers depends on the content, so I can't have a **fixed height** neither for the container nor for the boxes :/

Comment: @edo I suggest you to explain the same in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.header{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #ff9900;
}
.l1,.l2{
  width:33%;
  float:left;
  border:1px solid green;
  height:100px;
  margin-right:1px;
}
.l3{
  float:right;
  width:32%;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.a1,.a2,.a3,.a4{
  width:24%;
  float:left;
  border:1px solid green;
  height:100px;
  margin-right:1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<h1>header</h1>
</div>
<div class="body">
<div class="l1">
  <div style="width:100%; height:50%; background:#ff8800;">1</div>
  <div style="width:100%; height:50%; background:#ffff00;">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="l2">3</div>
  <div class="l3">4</div>
</div>
<br/>
This Is Next Lay Out

<div class="header">
<h1>header</h1>
</div>
<div class="body">
<div class="a1">
  <div style="width:100%; height:50%; background:#ff8800;">1</div>
  <div style="width:100%; height:50%; background:#ffff00;">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="a2">3</div>
  <div class="a3">4</div>
  <div class="a4">5</div>
</div>
```

Try It Once

Comment: Thanks, but this is not responsive. I need the same layout to work in both cases, depending on the screen width.